Can Expo[51] Bare Workflow App Run a Bundle Generated from react-native bundle Command?
I’m working with an ejected Expo SDK 51 app (bare workflow) and I want to bundle my JavaScript code using the react-native bundle command instead of the default Expo bundling process. (npx expo export)

Expo SDK: 51
React Native: 0.74.3
JavaScript Engine: JSC (JavaScriptCore, not Hermes)
Workflow: Bare (ejected from Expo)
Bundling Command: I would like to generate the JavaScript bundle using the following command:

react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ./output/main.jsbundle --platform ios --dev false --assets-dest ./output

My Question:

Is it possible for my Expo app (running JSC) to correctly load and run a JavaScript bundle generated by the react-native bundle command, instead of using expo export or expo publish?
If so, are there any additional steps or configurations I need to take into account when running this manually generated bundle in the Expo environment?

Any advice or clarification on this would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Yes, ejected Expo SDK 51 app (bare workflow) can run a JavaScript bundle generated by the react-native bundle command.
Should make sure that:

Loading the bundle correctly on the AppDelegate.m file:

jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];

